# Converting high-res timestamps to normal in a SQL table

Tags: sql, timestamp, type-conversion, date-conversion

I have a table with high-resolution timestamps (six decimals), in the form HH.MM.SS.xxxxxx

I want to convert these to ordinary HH:MM:SS time. Is there a cool way to do this? I have about 40 million rows, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE your_time
SET your_column = format(your_column , 'HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: I wanted to actually convert the data in the table to drop the highres data. Sorry if that wasn't clear.